# Removing legend from seaborn barplot but keeping custom color

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barplot with custom colors based on one of the column in the df. However I don't want legend to display. As soon as I try to remove legend color is back to default.

Here is my code.

```
b = sns.barplot(x="game_week", y="shots", data=data, hue="color")
b.tick_params(labelsize=5)
b.legend_.remove()
b.set(ylim=(0, np.nanmax(df[cols])))
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible with sns.barplot?

Comment: running some dummy code, It appears I'm getting the same coloring with or without the legend? I'm running sns 0.9.1 and matplotlib 3.0.3. I did omit the `b.set()` line. Maybe see if that does anything?

Comment: doesn't help. do you get hue from data.frame or hardcoding it?

Comment: I used the same exact line you had: `b = sns.barplot(x="game_week", y="shots", data=data, hue="color")`.

Comment: `all code, replace \n:` import seaborn as sns\nimport pandas as pd\nimport numpy as np\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt\nimport matplotlib\ndata = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 3)), columns=['game_week', 'shots', 'color'])\nb = sns.barplot(x="game_week", y="shots", data=data, hue="color")\nb.tick_params(labelsize=5)\nb.legend_.remove()\nplt.figure()\nc = sns.barplot(x="game_week", y="shots", data=data, hue="color")\nc.tick_params(labelsize=5)\nplt.show()\nprint(sns.__version__)\nprint(matplotlib.__version__)

Comment: just ran it with  `b.set(ylim=(0, np.nanmax(data["shots"])))` before plotting. I get a colored bar plot without a legend and a custom maximum

Comment: @Warlax56 Thank you so much for `nb.legend_.remove()`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the color palette with [seaborn.color_palette](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html) like this:

```py
palette = sns.color_palette('hls', len(data.color.unique())

ax = sns.barplot(
     x="game_week", 
     y="shots", 
     data=data, 
     hue="color",
     palette=palette
)
ax.legend_.remove()
```

By setting the palette this way you will get a number of colors corresponding to the number of categories in the `color` column of your dataframe that is also **colorblind friendly**!